# How to get value higher or lower from outer reference (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, one with **data for materials** and what costing lot size they currently have. Then I have another table containing **purchase scales** for the same materials. I then need to fetch the **purchase scale** that are the same or smaller than my costing lot size from the original table and the **purchase scale** just above it. This works for me as a correlated sub query within my select sentence:

```
Select 
mbew.Matnr as Material
,mbew.bwkey as Plant
,mbew.STPRS/mbew.peinh as Standard_price
,mbew.verpr/mbew.peinh as Average_price
,keko.Costing_lot_size
,Keko.Costing_date
,(select max(info.scale_quantity_konm) as Scale_quantity from dwh.inforecords info where mbew.matnr = info.material and keko.costing_lot_size >= info.scale_quantity_konm) as Current_Costing_Lot_Size
,(select min(info.scale_quantity_konm) as Scale_quantity from dwh.inforecords info where mbew.matnr = info.material and keko.costing_lot_size < info.scale_quantity_konm) as Next_Costing_Lot_Size
,inforecords_larger_price.amount_dkk_konm as Next_Costing_Lot_Size_Price


from 
mbew mbew

left join

(Select kekoa.Material, kekoa.Plant, kekoa.Costing_date, kekoa.Costing_lot_size
from sap.keko Kekoa

inner join 
(select Material, Plant, max(costing_date) as Lates_costing_date from sap.keko
group by material, plant) kekob

on kekoa.costing_date = kekob.Lates_costing_date
and kekoa.Material = kekob.material
and kekoa.plant  = kekob.plant) as keko

on 
mbew.matnr = keko.material
and mbew.bwkey = keko.Plant
```

But it is **highly inefficient**. Can it somehow be made smarter/optimized?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should add the entiry query

Comment: I have added the entire query now. Hope that helps :-)